# Magento coupons and subscriptions extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, magento-connect, coupon

**Following are the requirements:**

1. Subscription for Goody Bag with online payment  2 - Payment
   should be one time
2. Subscription plan should be of 3 Months,6 Months and respective delivery
3. If the customer is purchasing for the first time then the system should generate discount coupon code to that customer.
4. Discount coupon code should be generated with Thank you mail (Purchase order final mailEx. This is your purchase.Thank you for subscribing ABC etc. kind of mail)
5. If That customer does not want to use the coupon code, he can share it with his family/friends etc.But that family member/friend can not share that coupon code.
6. The coupon should have the expiry date.Coupon can be share via mail or facebook.

**How to do this in Magento with cost effective manner?**